Including a Linux library in VS solution so that it's copied correctly
I have a .NET C# solution, developed on Windows but intended for deployment on a Linux machine. It comprises several projects: "lanucher" project, UI project (Blazor) Lib project, and "Hardware lib" project.
The solution already includes some Linux libraries, (added by NuGet packages), such as libe_sqlite3.so, libSkiaSharp.so, libSystem.IO.Ports.Native.so.
When I publish the main project to a folder, (target runtime linux-x64), these libraries are copied directly into the output folder.
I'm also doing some debugging in VS Code on a Linux machine, in this case the build project puts the libs in bin/Debug/net8.0/runtimes/linux-x64/native.
I have a library file which I got from a hardware manufacturer, which the application needs to control the hardware. I copied the library manually to both aforementioned locations, and in both cases it works.
I need to include the file in the solution in such way that it is copied with the rest of the libs during both publish and normal build in VS/VS Code. How can I do this?
Thank you.
